# Setting a LinearLayout in ListView with vertical orientation

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I am experimenting with setting a custom listview layout. The layout I inflate is this:

test.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="hello"
        />
    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="hello 2"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

this looks normal like this:

[image]

but then when i change the orientation of the linear layout to horizontal is messes up and looks like this: **Is there any way to fix this or what am i doing wrong here?**
[image]

**Again is there any way to fix this or what am i doing wrong here?**

Comment: Try doing android:layout_width="wrap_content" in the text views. Doe sit make a difference?

Comment: you can use layout weight

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make both TextViews' width as "wrap_content"

SInce you have made orientation as horizontal, and the First textview has width as match_parent therefore the first textview took all the width and second textview could not come after it.